# Java Eclipse Indigo issue

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration

I was working with Eclipse(Indigo 3.7.2) in Windows XP (32 bit). Later I got new Windows7 (64 Bit) machine. Now I have copied all the Eclipse folder and sub folder to my new system from my older one.

My question is will the same version of Eclipse work on windows7 system?. If yes what are all files needs to be changed.

Current Eclipse.ini looks like :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\j2re1.4.2_17\bin
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
```

Error Log:

> !SESSION 2015-12-01 13:16:44.702
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800 java.version=1.4.2_17 java.vendor=Sun
>   Microsystems Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32,
>   NL=en_AU Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -Xms512m -Xmx2048m Command-line
>   arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -clean -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -Xms512m -Xmx2048m
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 4 0 2015-12-01
>   13:16:52.674 !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle
>   "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins_1.1.100.v20110815-1419
>   [293]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint:
>   Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.extensionlocation;
>   version="0.0.0"   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1327)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1311)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

Comment: "plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502" I think that line would be changed because of "win32.x86". It looks like you needed something similar to "win64.x64" isn't it? (I'm not sure)

Comment: That didn't work mate.

Comment: Oh :/. Well, do you really need indigo? Have you considered another version as Mars or something similar?

Comment: It looks like it is having trouble finding the 'org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.extensionlocation' plugin. You would probably be better off doing a clean install from a new Eclipse download (and perhaps move to the latest Eclipse Mars with Java 8).